# Test statistic distribution in a cointegrating regression

Tags: time-series, cointegration

Let's assume I have a simple cointegrating regression of the type

$$y_t=\beta_0+\beta_1x_t+\varepsilon_t$$

$y,x$ are $I(1)$.

If testing the OLS residuals I find that $y$ and $x$ are cointegrated, how can I perform tests on the coefficients? Are the two estimators distributed as a usual t-student? Which critical values should I use?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Charlie, I recommend two things.

First, have a read through De Boef and Keele (2008) for a really decent overview of different time series models, *especially* how they relate to one another.

Second, consider using a single equation generalized error correction model (described in the preceding paper, and in more detail in Banerjee, et al. 1993), which has several attractive qualities, including:

- estimation of instantaneous short run effects
- estimation of lagged short run effects
- estimation of long run equilibrium effects
- desirable estimation properties (see De Boef, 2001)
- model agnosticism as to the stationarity/non-stationarity of model predictors
- ready correspondence to other dynamic model forms (e.g. ADL(1)).

The basic form of the single equation generalized error correction model is:

$\Delta y_{t} = \beta_{0} + \beta_{\text{c}}\left(y_{t-1}-x_{t-1}\right) + \beta_{\Delta x}\Delta x_{t} + \beta_{x}x_{t-1} + \varepsilon$

These models can be extended to incorporate multiple predictors, more lags, random effects, etc.

**References**

Banerjee, A., Dolado, J. J., Galbraith, J. W., and Hendry, D. F. (1993). *Co-integration, error correction, and the econometric analysis of non-stationary data*. Oxford University Press, USA.

De Boef, S. (2001). Modeling equilibrium relationships: Error correction models with strongly autoregressive data. *Political Analysis*, 9(1):78–94.

De Boef, S. and Keele, L. (2008). Taking time seriously. *American Journal of Political Science*, 52(1):184–200.